# Changes in velocity file (. vm) file requires restart

Tags: velocity

Does it takes restart for the .vm file changes?

Also, for database changes does it takes restart?

Comment: Depends on your application server. Sometime hot code replace works sometimes not. Concerning changes to the db: depends on what you change and how you access the database

Comment: I am using Suna Application Server. Also, for db, I am changing a column value ( a simple update).

Comment: unless you use some kind of caching - the update should not require a restart

Answer (score 1):

Changes to velocity macros may or may not require a restart. This depends on your configuration... typically on a production system you would want to configure velocity to cache the macros to improve performance but on a development system you're likely to want more flexibility and therefore switch off caching.

I'm not sure what method for configuring velocity you use, I use a properties file and these are the settings I would use switch off caching:

```
webapp.resource.loader.cache=false
velocimacro.library.autoreload=true
velocimacro.permissions.allow.inline.to.replace.global=true
```

NB: you may need to replace "webapp" with the appropriate resource loader if you use a different one

Database changes certainly shouldn't require a restart

Comment: Thanks for the comments. I am using the Sun Java™ System Application Server. Can you tell me the location where when I place jar the changes will be reflected.

Comment: I guess you're saying that your .vm files are inside your jar. You'll probably need to unpack the jar for this solution to work